# What is the significance of number 8 (八) in Japanese?

Tags: kanji, etymology, numbers

I've noticed a couple of words with the character 八 that have (seemingly) nothing to do with the number 8.

- 八百屋【やおや】 - greengrocer
- 八つ【やつ】当たり【あたり】 - taking out anger on someone
- 八丁【はっちょう】 - skillfullness

Furthermore, this is the only number which I've noticed this pattern on. All other words consisting a number have a much more obvious relation, (even when it's a 一).

---

On jisho.org, the [count of #words](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%85%AB%20%23words) containing each of the numeral characters shows a noticeable spike on 八 as well.

```
一    二   三    四   五   六   七   八   九   十
1713  787  1264  438  364  196  172  357  308  320
```

---

And here's a table of how common each is in newspapers. Doesn't really show anything but I thought to include it since I looked into it as well. I wonder what the count would be if 九州【きゅうしゅう】 was stripped from the count on 九.

```
一    二   三    四   五   六   七   八   九   十
2     9    14    47   31   93   115  92   55   8
```

Comment: I think in most cases, the number 8 is involved even though we don't realize it.  For example, the following explains at least one of those situations: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20951/22352

Comment: Related: [Why “greengrocer” kanjis are 八百屋 (やおや)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19307/19278)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one puzzled me, so I did some digging.

I couldn't find anything definitive on where the "many" meaning may have come from.  This kanji *does* seem to have this meaning in Chinese as well, as we see over at [the Wiktionary entry for the Chinese term](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%AB#Chinese), and also over in [the Unihan entry](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E5%85%AB).

This is conjecture, but I suspect the "many" sense may come from the idea of the eight directions -- the four cardinals, and the four in-betweens: north, south, east, west, northeast, northwest, southeast, southwest.

The "many" sense appears to be quite old in Japanese, and it's specific to the *kun'yomi* or native Japanese term, so I don't think this was an import from the Chinese.  However, the sense development may have been similar in both languages -- "eight" → "eight directions" → "all over, all directions" → "many, various".

Answer (score 0):

Some words(mainly from old days) have 八 to imply "all" or "so many".
八百屋 is an example of this.(so many)

and as one number. It's one of a good number because the character 八 looks wider to lower(Kanji is written top to bottom, meaning prosperity)